# Code design for a Cartesian product of cases

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a an algorithm that goes according to the following logic:

Two parameters `x` and `y` take values in `A={1,2,3,4}` and `B={'a','b','c'}`, respectively.

Depending on the values of the pairs `(x,y)` the algorithm should execute a series corresponding set of steps `f_x_y`, but don't think of `f_x_y` as a piece of code parametrized by `x` and `y`. The instructions that need to be executed for `(x,y)=(1,'a')` are different from those corresponding to `(2,'c')`. Different pieces of code, one for each pair in the Cartesian product of `A` and `B`.
The sets `A` and `B` are not too large. Their sizes are pretty much as above.

I have considered the following options:

**Option 1:** An implementation using `if`s.

```
if x == 1:
  if y == 'a':
    f_1_a
  elif y == 'b':
    f_1_b # Remember that it is not a function, but an entirely different piece of code as f_1_a
  # Rest of the cases inside x=1
elif x == 2:
  if y == 'a':
    f_2_a
# etc.
```

**Option 2:** A map from cases to functions.

```
def f_1_a():
  pass
def f_1_b():
  pass
# ...
cases = {(1,'a'):f_1_a,(1,'b'):f_1_b,} # ...
cases[(x,y)]()
```

**Question:** Which of these, or other alternative, should I prefer?

My gut feeling is that the second would be easy to modify if there are new requirements.

I don't have enough experience to tell if any is preferable for being faster.

Comment: It has some similarities, but I am not sure if [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) would be what my question is about.

Comment: Very interesting question !

Comment: Might be more useful for us to understand the problem, instead of judging two different designs that might be completely overdesign for your requirements.

Comment: @EatonEmmerich I didn't understand. What is what you are suggesting that I should do to make the question better to understand?

Comment: The question is pretty clear to me!

Comment: Could you create an object called 'coordinates', that contains the X and Y values? and switch on it instead?

Comment: @EatonEmmerich That is what Option 2 is doing. The pairs `(1,'a'), (2,'b'),...` are the immutable objects, one for each pair. Next is not a hand-written switch, but  a dictionary mapping these objects (keys) to each piece of code that needs to be executed in each case. Finally, there is the call to whichever code is required `cases[(x,y)]()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From performance perspective:** The second approach is better.
The reason is the fact that branching (i.e. `if`'s and `else`'s) causes the pipeline of instructions for the CPU to be wiped out, which means we lose any pre-loaded instructions in the pipeline, while accessing a map element is just a matter of calculating the hash of a key.
Although this is true for compiled languages, I don't think it's much different in case of Python.
**From design perspective:** Still the second approach is better.
Just like you said, it is easier to add/remove/edit any of the requirements, you just need to lookup the corresponding key. While in the first approach, you have to navigate your way around those 'ugly' `if`'s and `else`'s.

Comment: still can't pre-load the next function if it's defined within the map, technically in some cases calculating the hash is much slower than having a few if cases.

Comment: Actually, no. The map will boil down to an array of indices -> pointers, where each index points to the address of the corresponding function. calculating the hash is a simple arithmetic operation and fits well in the pipeline. having a bunch of if and else will pre-load instructions and then wipe them when hitting the truthy value.
Also keep in mind that the map will probably be loaded into the cache since it's small, so you have two reasons now that a map is faster :)

Comment: whether the map fits in the cache doesn't matter, the correct function isn't guaranteed to be in the pipeline unless the hash is calculated first.

Comment: No function will be in the pipeline, what gets into the pipeline is instructions, like MOV or ADD. when you have if and else, all those instructions will be loaded into the pipeline and then wiped out. in the case of the map, only one instruction will be loaded into the pipeline: the mov to call the hash function, nothing will be wiped out. having the map in the cache is a huge boost because you won't need to fetch the address of the function after branching like in the case of if and else.

Comment: Sure, it will always be the same hash function.... but the hash function will result in a MOV to one of many funcs, just like in the if cases, It's possible to use a switch instead and have the same behaviour (comparing a integer so no hashing) with the same result

Comment: @EatonEmmerich Sometimes in a branching the processor loads and maybe even computes some of the instructions of one of the branches. I think it is called branch prediction. When the condition is finally evaluated, it can happen that the predicted branch is not the right one. So, the correct branch needs to be loaded and executed.

Comment: @plop: python is *mostly* an interpreted language. It is very hard to predict its behaviour in terms of CPU instructions. There is a large chance that every data-reference will cause some level of cache miss. For code paths it is hard to predict, *maybe* except for the built-ins.

Comment: I agree plop, but there is no proof that using a hash map to select a branch is easier to predict than a series of if statements

Comment: Ok, let's consider the worst case where the branching has to reach for the last else (or case in a switch branching). Consider a 5 x 5 cartesian product, this is obviously much much slower than a simple lookup! (by ~ 25 x). Even with no guarantees that if else is slow, you are still guaranteed that a map will be at least as fast.

Comment: I concede, sorry. I was under the impression that python would automatically optimize a switch statement to a jump table, learned something today.